# Using ajax to call a php function, inside that function calling another function that wont fire

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Im using ajax on the front end to submit wp_query filters($args)
I have a function in my functions.php called filter_function() this is what the ajax is submiting to.

Inside filter_function() I have another function  distance_haversine() getting called thats inside my functions.php file but that function will not work inside filter_function()

Example:

```
function distance_haversine($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
      global $earth_radius;
      global $delta_lat;
      global $delta_lon;
      $alpha    = $delta_lat/2;
      $beta     = $delta_lon/2;
      $a   = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) *           cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
      $c        = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
      $distance = 2*$earth_radius * $c;
      $distance = round($distance, 4);

      return $distance;

}


function filter_function(){

if ( isset( $_POST['distance_miles']  ) ) { 

  $distance_miles  = $_POST['distance_miles'];

} else {

   $distance_miles  = 50;

}



$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => $_POST['date'], 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    's' => $_POST['search'],
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
      $event_lat     = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'prod-lat',true);
      $event_long    = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'prod-lng',true);
      $full_location = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'prod-full-address',true); 
      $earth_radius = 3960.00; # in miles
      $lat_1 = $event_lat;
      $lon_1 = $event_long;
      $lat_2 = $user_lat;
      $lon_2 = $user_long;
      $delta_lat = $lat_2 - $lat_1;
      $delta_lon = $lon_2 - $lon_1;

    //$lat_1, $lon_1, $lat_2, $lon_2 all have values

    $hav_distance = distance_haversine($lat_1, $lon_1, $lat_2, $lon_2);//this is not working

    var_dump($hav_distance); //<------**This is outputing "float(0)"**

    if ( $hav_distance <= $distance_miles ) { 

?>

<li>
    <a href="">              
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>        
        <?php } else { ?>
            <img src="/place-holder.jpeg">
        <?php  }; ?>                
    </a>
</li>

<?php }

  endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

  else :

    echo 'No posts found';

  endif;

  die();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have so many opening and closing php tags line after line?

Comment: what do you mean @lce76

Comment: Start debugging (especially the parameters from the request - I would bet they're empty)

Comment: i did every thing has values  $lat_1, $lon_1, $lat_2, $lon_2 all have values. but once i use them in distance_haversine() it outputs float(0)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: float(0) @Ice76

Comment: you dont get a compiler error, seems like it is a logical error with you function then returning 0. Test it more with pre defined inputs to get expected results, then test the current inputs

Comment: distance_haversine() works 100% when I call it outside the functions.php

Comment: What is global set to? @Tsea

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function filter_function(){
      global $earth_radius;
      global $delta_lat;
      global $delta_lon;
.....
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.